Number of unit cubes meeting the boundary of a convex set
Suppose $C \subseteq [0,n)^k$ is a convex set, and $\partial C$ is its topological boundary: its closure minus its interior. Is it true that $\partial C$ meets at most $2kn^{k-1}$ unit cubes in [0,n)^k? By a unit cube, I mean a set of the form $[n_1,n_1 + 1) \times [n_2, n_2 + 1) \times \ldots \times [n_k, n_k + 1)$? where $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ are integers.
I'm motivated by the fact that if $C_1 \subseteq C_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ are convex, then their surface areas are related by $\text{SA}(C_1) \leq \text{SA}(C_2)$. So the surface area of $C \subseteq [0,n)^k$ is maximized when $C = [0,n)^k$ which has surface area $2k n^{k-1}$. The number of unit cubes that meet $\partial C$ should be roughly its surface area.

@AlexRavsky A convex set C in [0,n) is just an interval. Its boundary $\partial C$ consists of its endpoints, so it meets at most 2 cubes. If $k = 1$, then $2k n^{k-1} = 2$

Why is it not enough to consider$C=[0,n)^k$? Also, if $C=[0,1)$ which of the $9$ cubes with lower left-hand corners at the points $(a,b)$, $a,b$ in $-1,0,1$ does $\partial C$ meet?

@Steen82 it is not enough to consider $C = [0,n)^k$ since I don't see a proof that if $C_1 \subset C_2 \subset [0,n)^k$ are both convex, then the number of cubes meeting $\partial C_1$ is $\leq$ the number of cubes meeting $\partial C_2$. Your second question doesn't make sense since $C = [0,1)$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Perhaps you mean $C = [0,1) \times {0}$ in which case $\partial C = [0,1] \times {0}$ which meets the two cubes with corners that the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Sorry for the typo, should not try to type on my phone. I meant $[0,1)^2.$ But I think you answered my question.

A small remark: any unit cube meeting $\partial C$ must be contained in the ball of radius $\sqrt{k}$ around $\partial C$. So since the surface area of $C$ is at most $2kn^{k-1}$, the measure of the $\sqrt{k}$-ball around $\partial C$ is at most $O(k^{1.5} n^{k-1})$. Hence the number of unit cubes that meet $\partial C$ is at most $O(k^{1.5} n^{k-1})$. I am interested in improving this bound to $O(k n^{k-1})$.
